# using memcmp to compare buffers with 0 bytes

Tags: c

I am trying to compare 2 texts from files byte by byte using memcmp, after I read both of them into memory, one file into a buffer(char* or char[], tried both). the problem is, the file I read into a buffer have a lot of 0 bytes, which makes him stop at the first 0 byte thinking it is a null terminating zero, which makes a segmentation fault. how can I make the function keep compare bytes even so there are 0 bytes?

I already tried to check if the buffer is full or not, I printed it byte by byte and it showed all of the bytes including the 0 bytes. when I print it completely using printf("%s", buffer) I get only the first byte(the second byte is 0 byte).

```
void detect_virus(char *buffer, unsigned int size){
    link* l = (link*) malloc(sizeof(link));
    load(l);
    unsigned int location = 0;
    while(l != NULL){
        location = 0;
        while(location < size - l->vir->SigSize){
            int isVirus = memcmp(buffer + location, l->vir->sig, l->vir->SigSize);
            if(isVirus == 0)
                printf("%d, %s, %d\n", location, l->vir->virusName, l->vir->SigSize);
            location++;
        }
    }
    free(l);
}

void detect(link* list){
    char filename[50];
    fgets(filename, 50, stdin);
    sscanf(filename, "%s", filename);
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(10000);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, file);
    detect_virus(buffer, size);
    fclose(file);
}
```

I get a segmentation fault at the first time the memcmp function is called, instead of fully compare the texts. any ideas how to fix that?

**edit**
code for `load` function:

```
void load(link* list){
    printf("Enter Viruses file name: \n");
    char* filename = (char*) malloc(100);
    fgets(filename, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(filename, "%s", filename);
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    while(!feof(file)){
        short length = 0;
        fread(&length, 2, 1, file);
        if(length == 0)
            break;
        struct virus* v = (struct virus*)malloc(length);
        fseek(file, -2, SEEK_CUR);
        fread(v, length, 1, file);
        v->SigSize = v->SigSize - 18;
        list_append(list, v);
    }
    list = list->nextVirus;
    free(filename);
    fclose(file);
}
```

as a note, I tested the function before and it worked.

***edit***
I found out the problem, thank you all!

Comment: Can you add the code for "load" function. Your code is "correct" (with that sscanf that I don't understand) and you don't think your problem is '0' bytes, because memcmp compares buffers not strings. But I'm suspecting the "load" function to be the cause, because of the allocation is done of 'l'.

Comment: The issue is unrelated to `memcmp`.

Comment: @MeherKhiari edited now

Comment: I don't see anything that can have an impact (although i recommend to remove those sscanf, because they are useless and can cause undefined behaviour as stated below). You have to compile it with debug symbols, get the core dump and analyse the backtrace, at least you'll have the point of crash. Then you can break on it and check the values of your variables. Good luck :)

Comment: @MeherKhiari the core dump happens at the line where I call the memcmp function. The value of buffer is "b" but when I print buffer byte by byte I get all the file as expected. b is the first byte in the file, the second one is 0 byte and I think it stops because of the 0 byte, but I dont know why or how to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Per [**7.21.6.7 The sscanf function**, paragraph 2 of the C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.7p2) (bolding mine):

> The `sscanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf`, except that input is obtained from a string (specified by the argument `s`) rather than from a stream. Reaching the end of the string is equivalent to encountering end-of-file for the `fscanf` function. **If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.**

Note the bolded portion.

In your code:

```
sscanf(filename, "%s", filename);
```

the `filename` array certainly overlaps with the `filename` array, thus invoking undefined behavior.

Remove that line of code.

You also need to add error checking, especially checking that the return from `fopen()` is not `NULL`.

Comment: actually I changed that and I get segmentation fault even earlier, but that's not my problem. The file is found and read into the buffer, but when I try to compare it, it stops at 0 byte and then I get segmentation fault.
about error checking you are right, I will add them.

Comment: @OrelVaknin The problem might very well be in the code you didn't post.  Your `while(l != NULL){` looks like it probably has issues as you never modify `l` in the loop.

Comment: you are right I forgot I am fixing a few things here. but still the problem happens at the first iteration of the while, and that's the main problem I have right now